# Windows 10 Pro not seeing any other machines on the network, what am I missing?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10

When I visit `\\network` on my new laptop that is running Windows 10 Pro (for Workstation), most often I can't see any other machines, like in this screenshot:

[image]

Sometimes I see printers and/or streaming servers, but what I never see is the other computers (one Windows 10 Home, one Windows 10 Pro, and a Drobo).

The network is marked as a private one:

[image]

and private networks have network discovery on as well as file and printer sharing:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I also tried enabling and disabling SMB 1.0/CIFS to no avail:

[image]

What am I missing?